# How to run different methods on strings through a variable?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, methods

The question asks me to create an empty list and follow the commands down the input. The first line tells me how many commands there are in total followed by said commands.

Here is a sample input:

```
12             # Number of commands
insert 0 5     # L = [5] (insert 5 in position 0)
insert 1 10    # L = [5, 10] (insert 10 in position 1)
insert 0 6     # L = [6, 5, 10] (insert 6 in position 0)
print          # print [6, 5, 10]
remove 6       # L = [5, 10]
append 9       # L = [5, 10, 9]
append 1       # L = [5, 10, 9, 1]
sort           # L = [1, 5, 9, 10]
print          # print [1, 5, 9, 10]
pop            # L = [1, 5, 9]
reverse        # L = [9, 5, 1]
print          # print [9, 5, 1]
```

so my output is:

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

here is my current code:

```
list = []    
count = int(input())
for z in range(0, count):
    command = input().split()
    if len(command) is 1:
        command(list)
    elif len(command) is 2:
        list.command[0](command[1])
    else:
        list.insert(int(command[1]), int(command[2]))
```

I have an error of `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'command'`

I'm attempting to use the string in command[0] which can be `insert`, `remove`, `append` (or command if it is only `print`, `sort`, or `reverse`) but python is literally taking the term 'command' instead of the string it is holding in memory, is there a way around this without making if/else statements for every single method case?

Comment: What's your python version (run `python --version`)? You say 3.x but if it's running 2.7, this may be an issue of `input()` vs `raw_input()`

Comment: You want a mapping, I guess, that roughly looks like {"append": list.append}, and so on.

Comment: You don't want to use variables as your method/object call. Instead use an if statement that does the following: if (command[0] == "sort") then list.sort(blah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command` does not magically become the right function or attribute, no.

You could use `getattr()` to get an attribute from an object:

```
command = (insert, 0, 5)
getattr(list, command[0])(*command[1:])
```

but that'll get cumbersome as you need to keep testing how many arguments you have and handle the `print` case separately.

Better to use a *dictionary* mapping commands to functions:

```
commands = {
    'print': lambda: print(list),
    'insert': lambda pos, value: list.insert(pos, value),
    # etc.
}
```

then call the command via a dictionary lookup, applying the remaining values as arguments:

```
commands[command[0]](*command[1:])
```

You could even insert bound methods; `list.pop` and `list.insert` take just the right arguments after all.

Note that you want to avoid `list` as a variable name, really. Use `stack` perhaps. Using Python 3, you can also use a catch-all target when assigning, letting you split out the command and the arguments in one step:

```
stack = []
commands = {
    'print': lambda: print(stack),
    'insert': stack.insert,
    'pop': stack.pop,
    'remove': stack.remove,
    'append': stack.append,
    'sort': stack.sort,
    'reverse': stack.reverse,
}

count = int(input())
for z in range(count):
    command, *args = input().split()
    commands[command[0]](*args)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you made stack into a dict `{}` rather than a list `[]`?

Comment: @AndyWong: nope, that was a typo, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you want is `getattr`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 5]
>>> command = "append"
>>> arg = 7
>>> a.command(arg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'command'
>>> getattr(a, command)
<built-in method append of list object at 0x10f9710e0>
>>> getattr(a, command)(arg)
>>> a
[1, 2, 5, 7]
```

Also, don't call the list `list` since that variable already exists in the global namespace.